# No Network device detected Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, 14.04

It works okay from my first install of 14.04, but after several updates made due to some applications that requires update, it suddenly disappear. Even the modem manager were it used to detect my usb modem were not working anymore.

On the live CD, the network works fine including my USB  modem is usable. My target is to fix first the network thing cause I can have an internet sharing using my other desktop, but that won't work if I don't have my network device working.

Here's my info that might help for helping me

```
lspci -nn | grep -e 0200 -e 0280
```

Output:

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
```